# Android: emoji as keyLabel on custom keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, emoji

I am developing a custom keyboard. But for emojis, I can't set unicode emoji characters as **android:keyLabel**. I *don't* want to use **android:keyIcon**.

`\uxxxx` will not work for `U+10000` and higher. emoticons start from `U+1F600`. so how can I change this code span to use emoji as keyLabel?

```
<Row>
  <Key android:codes="-100" android:keyLabel="\u1F600"/>
  ... 
</Row>
```

I know, this will not work. So is it possible to do the same without using keyIcon?
Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make view see :

```
<resources>
    <array
        name="emoji_nature"
        format="string"
    >
        <!-- <item>1f415</item> -->
        <item>1f436</item>
        <item>1f429</item>
```

That is emoji unidcode define in **values** folder and

this resource array used to **xml/emoji_nature.xml**

**Code :**

```
<Keyboard
    xmlns:latin="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    latin:keyWidth="@fraction/config_emoji_keyboard_key_width"
    latin:keyLetterSize="90%p"
    latin:keyLabelSize="60%p"
    latin:rowHeight="@fraction/config_emoji_keyboard_row_height"
>
    <GridRows
        latin:textsArray="@array/emoji_nature"
        latin:keyLabelFlags="fontNormal"
        latin:backgroundType="empty" />
</Keyboard>
```

**2nd Solution**

**change Code** 
**SoftKeyboard.java**

```
private void handleCharacter(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        if (getCurrentInputConnection() == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (isInputViewShown()) {
            if (mInputView.isShifted()) {
                primaryCode = Character.toUpperCase(primaryCode);
            }
        }

        getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(String.valueOf(Character.toChars(primaryCode)), 1);



    }
```

Thanks cool and enjoy **Solved problem**